# Specify assembly version number as a command line argument in MSBuild

Tags: msbuild, versioning

I would like to be able to specify the version number for all assemblies to be generated during a build as a MSBuild command argument like this:

```
MSBuild.exe /p:version=5.4.3.0
```

I have looked over `AssemblyInfoTask` but it does not seem to me like a good solution in this case.

Comment: Why is the AssemblyInfo task not suitable for you?  It's purpose *is* to set assembly information, including the version number (AssemblyVersion) attribute.

Comment: The version number need to be set up based on some external rules not on some rules that can be built-in using AssemblyInfoTask. Basically I want the command line argument to become the version number.

Comment: I used https://www.nuget.org/packages/MSBuild.AssemblyVersion/ package to achieve this.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I use the AssemblyInfo task as you describe in your comment all the time.

```
  <!-- update standard assembly attribute in all projects -->
  <Target Name="BeforeBuild" >
    <Message Text="Updating AssemblyInfo to Version $(VersionNumber)"></Message>
    <Message Text="Writing to AssemblyInfo files in $(SolutionRoot)"></Message>
    <AssemblyInfo AssemblyInfoFiles="@(AssemblyInfoFiles)" 
                  AssemblyCopyright="$(AssemblyCopyright)" 
                  AssemblyVersion="$(VersionNumber)"
                  AssemblyFileVersion="$(VersionNumber)"
                  >
    </AssemblyInfo>
  </Target>
```

The VersionNumber value is passed from outside the MSBuild project file exactly as you describe:

```
  MSBuild <project_file> /p:VersionNumber=<value>;...
```

We use the BeforeBuild target to ensure the AssemblyInfo.cs files all get worked on before the build starts. Is this not what you want?

Comment: When I try this I get an error that says the AssemblyInfo task is not found. I googled for "AssemblyInfo task" and installed something by that name as an MSBuild extension, but that didn't work. Could you provide a link to the one you're using?

Comment: @DennisPalmer , we use the task from the [MSBuild Extension Pack](http://msbuildextensionpack.codeplex.com/). Include the ...tasks file in a PropertyGroup element and you should be good to go.

Comment: installing that extension pack did not help, I still have the error so I opened SO question here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13090933/assemblyinfo-not-found-and-msbuild-extension-pack-installed

Comment: could one of you please provide a minimal working example on GitHub or so?

Comment: Which Tasks file is needed?  Do we just add that to our solution?

Comment: @FlappySocks this is an abbreviated version of what we do in our build process:

`<PropertyGroup>

 <TPath>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\ExtensionPack\4.0\MSBuild.ExtensionPack.tasks</TPath>
</PropertyGroup>


<Import Project="$(TPath)"/>


<Target Name="BuildApplication">
...

<MSBuild Projects="AppAssemblyInfo.proj" <--spins over the AssemblyInfo.cs files
  Properties="MajorMinor=$(MajorMinor);VersionNumber=$(VersionNumber);ReleaseName=$(ReleaseName)" ToolsVersion="14.0" Targets="SetAllValues" ContinueOnError="false"
  />

 ... 
 rest of build process
`

Answer (score 50):

For SDK-style projects that are built using `dotnet.exe`, assembly version attributes are [generated automatically](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/project-sdk/msbuild-props#assembly-attribute-properties), so you can use `/p:Version=5.4.3.0` right out of the box.

If you use the old project format, you need to add the following `BeforeBuild` step to your `.csproj` file. **No need to use extra `.targets` and extension packs**, because MSBuild already has a nice [built-in task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/writecodefragment-task) which does most of the stuff:

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
  <ItemGroup>
    <AssemblyAttributes Include="AssemblyVersion">
      <_Parameter1>$(Version)</_Parameter1>
    </AssemblyAttributes>
  </ItemGroup>
  <MakeDir Directories="$(IntermediateOutputPath)" />
  <WriteCodeFragment Language="C#"
                     OutputFile="$(IntermediateOutputPath)Version.cs"
                     AssemblyAttributes="@(AssemblyAttributes)" />
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="$(IntermediateOutputPath)Version.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

Just make sure you remove the existing `AssemblyVersion` attribute because it will now be generated during build.

**Update 7/29/2020:**
[Michael Parker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1554346/michael-parker) has pointed out that if you use this approach and do a build from Visual Studio, you end up with an empty version in the `Version.cs` file. To overcome this, I suggest defining the default Version value in your `.csproj` or `Directory.Build.props` file as follows:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  ...
  <Version Condition="'$(Version)' == ''">1.0.0.0</Version>
</PropertyGroup>
```

This will set it to `1.0.0.0` if Version wasn't specified in the command line.

Comment: Note to self: Don't forget .Net Framework projects can also have SDK-style project files!

Comment: This answer seems to leave a Version.cs with an empty version inside when you run from visual studio and not on the command line / CI.

Comment: @MichaelParker thanks for pointing that out. I have updated the answer.

Comment: `<Target Name="BeforeBuild">` should be specified **after** `<Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />` line as I've just learned

Comment: You have to comment the lines `[assembly: AssemblyVersion` and `[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion` if you have a file Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs

Comment: Thanks @oleksa ! Your comment is important.

Comment: The in-built solution also works for .NET Framework SDK projects that are built by invoking msbuild.exe directly (using dotnet.exe isn't a requirement). I'd assume this is also true for .NET Core projects.

Answer (score 22):

I know this is an old question but Google leads me to here as top result.

I followed a simple solution in [updated link](https://web.archive.org/web/20210118064331/http://www.lionhack.com/2014/02/13/msbuild-override-assembly-version/) (thanks Peter for the updated link). No need for extension pack.

Basically what you need to do is add a "BuildCommon.targets" files and modify your csproj file accordingly to have the version number specified in msbuild like:

```
msbuild.exe abc.sln /p:Configuration=Release;VersionAssembly=1.2.3.4
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Should it be AssemblyVersion?

Comment: @Freidgeim: that depends on how you name that command switch in the BuildCommon.targets file. that's totally up to you :)

Comment: It's 2019... and this is still the simplest solution for setting some version numbers... sigh. Microsoft, please fix this.

Comment: They did, for dotnet.exe you can specify like you'd want `/p:Version=1.2.4`

Comment: This worked great for me. The linked article was very informative. Only snag I hit was that in my AssemblyInfo.cs files, I have 1.0.* instead of the 1.0.0.0 that the regex was looking for. Once I corrected that, it worked like a charm.

Comment: It seems the link is dead and I can't find a cached version. What kind of csproj modifications are needed for this solution?

Comment: Link here: 
https://web.archive.org/web/20210118064331/http://www.lionhack.com/2014/02/13/msbuild-override-assembly-version/

Answer (score 8):

The top answer is great, but I needed to make a few adjustments. We have a solution containing a mix of SDK and non-SDK projects. Further we also use `AspNetCompileMerge` for pre-compiling ASP.NET MVC 5 views. Using the property name `AssemblyAttributes` causes the target of `GenerateAssemblyInfo` from `AspNetCompileMerge.targets` to be executed and failing. So I finally arrived on the following target that is shared by the whole solution through `Directory.Build.props`:

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
    <Version Condition="'$(Version)' == ''">1.0.0.0</Version>
    <AssemblyVersion Condition="'$(AssemblyVersion)' == ''">$(Version.Split('-')[0])</AssemblyVersion>
    <FileVersion Condition="'$(FileVersion)' == ''">$(Version.Split('-')[0])</FileVersion>
    <InformationalVersion Condition="'$(InformationalVersion)' == ''">$(Version)</InformationalVersion>
</PropertyGroup>
<Target Name="NonSdkGenerateAssemblyInfo" DependsOnTargets="PrepareForBuild" BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild" Condition="('$(UsingMicrosoftNETSdk)' != 'True' And '$(GenerateAssemblyInfo)' != 'False')">
    <ItemGroup>
        <NonSdkAssemblyAttributes Include="AssemblyVersion">
            <_Parameter1>$(AssemblyVersion)</_Parameter1>
        </NonSdkAssemblyAttributes>
        <NonSdkAssemblyAttributes Include="AssemblyFileVersion">
            <_Parameter1>$(FileVersion)</_Parameter1>
        </NonSdkAssemblyAttributes>
        <NonSdkAssemblyAttributes Include="AssemblyInformationalVersion">
            <_Parameter1>$(InformationalVersion)</_Parameter1>
        </NonSdkAssemblyAttributes>
    </ItemGroup>
    <WriteCodeFragment AssemblyAttributes="@(NonSdkAssemblyAttributes)"
                       Language="C#"
                       OutputDirectory="$(IntermediateOutputPath)"
                       OutputFile="AssemblyInfo.cs">
        <Output TaskParameter="OutputFile" ItemName="Compile" />
        <Output TaskParameter="OutputFile" ItemName="FileWrites" />
    </WriteCodeFragment>
</Target>
```

You can add additional attributes if needed. The default version number is `1.0.0.0` and you can specify additional version numbers on the command line, mimicking SDK-behaviour:

- `AssemblyVersion` and `FileVersion` default to the value of `$(Version)` without the suffix. For example, if `$(Version)` is `1.2.3-beta.4`, then the value would be `1.2.3`.
- `InformationalVersion` defaults to the value of `$(Version)`.

Comment: this worked great!  tried so many solutions w/ and w/o extensions to do this - use a single version in the CLI and have it handle setting them all. cheers!

Answer (score 2):

The [top answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58631756/227110) is indeed good.  In addition here's a couple of clarifications/suggestions that might prove useful (and perhaps obvious from the above postings) to avoid any custom targets, BeforeBuild, etc.

- For SDK projects (i.e. no AssemblyInfo.cs): `/p:Version='1.0.0-patch'` will also work for msbuild.exe (and dotnet.exe of course) without *any* csproj changes.  Useful for example when targetting v3 Wix setup projects that *still* don't support dotnet.exe.  Plus you can assign $AssemblyVersion and $FileVersion to empty values since $Version will assign them automatically.
- For non-SDK projects, instead of modifying csproj with custom targets, BeforeBuild, etc then it might just be simpler/quicker to upgrade them to SDK style projects, i.e. remove the obsolete AssemblyInfo.cs usage.  Refer [migrating projects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/project-sdk/msbuild-props#assembly-attribute-properties).