# AssemblyInfo not found and msbuild extension pack installed

Tags: msbuild, msbuildextensionpack

I am trying to use the AssemblyInfo task and I just ran the msi for .net 4.0 for the MSBuild Extension pack.  After installation, I still get this error

"C:\AAROOT\csharpprojects\toolbar\project.build" (default target) (1) ->
(Compile target) ->
  C:\AAROOT\csharpprojects\toolbar\project.build(15,5): error MSB4036: The "Ass
emblyInfo" task was not found. Check the following: 1.) The name of the task in
 the project file is the same as the name of the task class. 2.) The task class
 is "public" and implements the Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask interface. 3.)

I don't see anything in the installation instructions that I would have to do.  I installed to the default location(in fact, it never asked me for a location).

documentation was at
http://msbuildextensionpack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Prereqs&referringTitle=Documentation

thanks,
Dean

Comment: Totally stupid question: you are Importing the Tasks file in your MS build project, yes?

Comment: glad you asked it as no, I was not....I thought from reading it auto picked it up since somewhere it said if you don't install in default location, you have to do extra...would be nice if they told us that in the docs....how to import, I guess I will peruse the docs more to find it.

Comment: Which tasks file is needed to import?