# Specify the assembly version for a DotNet Framework 4.7 project using msbuild via PowerShell

Tags: c#, powershell

I have this one liner that can publish my project:

```
& "$($linkToMSBuildEXE)" "$($solutionName)" /t:projectName /p:Configuration="Release"
```

I need to publish this project and set the assemblyVersion and fileVersion of the output executable. I have tried adding the version:

```
& "$($linkToMSBuildEXE)" "$($solutionName)" /t:projectName /p:Configuration="Release"/p:Version=1.1.1.1
```

This doesn't seem to work. Do I need to add an entry to the csproj file? How can I set the versions via the command line.

Comment: Please see the last answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8446693/specify-assembly-version-number-as-a-command-line-argument-in-msbuild

Comment: i came across that earlier, it seems convoluted to me, is there not a simpler way? I'm sure in dotnet core you can just specify /p:Version=1.2.3.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Install `MSBuild.AssemblyVersion` package from NuGet.
2. Use the following or similar command line:

   `msbuild project.csproj /t:Rebuild /p:AssemblyVersionNumber=1.2.3.4`

Comment: that works perfectly. Thanks, I'm not sure why this isn't out of the box -.-

Comment: MSBuild is a powerful tool. In .NET Core, the successor of .NET, Microsoft guys decided to equip it with more handy tasks and features that are based on the same possibilities.