# How to set System.Reflection.AssemblyVersionAttribute for Blazor

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I want to set the  System.Reflection.AssemblyVersionAttribute for a blazor-web-app without changing it allways manualy.

Google didn't know the answer :-(

How can I influence the value?

Thanks!
Peter

Answer (score 1):

[MSBump](https://github.com/BalassaMarton/MSBump) seems to work with .net5.0. Search it in nuget.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
        <Version>1.0.1.2</Version>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="MSBump" Version="2.3.2">
            <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
            <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
        </PackageReference>
    </ItemGroup>
    <PropertyGroup Condition="$(Configuration) == 'Debug'">
        <BumpLabel>dev</BumpLabel>
        <BumpLabelDigits>4</BumpLabelDigits>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup Condition="$(Configuration) == 'Release'">
        <BumpRevision>True</BumpRevision>
        <BumpResetLabel>dev</BumpResetLabel>
    </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Answer (score 0):

A way to change the value of AssemblyVersionAttribute is to use a msbuild task. This thread points out a good examples [Specify assembly version number as a command line argument in MSBuild](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8446693/specify-assembly-version-number-as-a-command-line-argument-in-msbuild). There is no difference between a "normal" app or a Blazor app.

If you want to use the version number, here is a sample component named *SiteFooter*

```
@using System.Reflection

<footer class="main-footer">
    <span>
        Version: @_version
    </span> 
</footer>

@code {

    private String _version = typeof(SiteFooter).Assembly.GetCustomAttribute<AssemblyFileVersionAttribute>().Version;

}
```