# Set Assembly Info in VS2008 VCPROJ over BuildPipline

Tags: azure-devops, msbuild

I need to integrate an older VS2008 project for WINCE6, without .NET, into an AzurePipline. This works very well with msbuild. Now I am looking for a way to set the version number in the version info.
Ready-made extensions did not work with the old project.
Probably the best way is to use a property of msbuild. I just don't know how to process the version number in the project.
Has anyone ever done something like this? Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

In your build pipeline on Azure DevOps, you can add an Assembly Info task to set assembly information of your application.

[Here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=Assembly&target=AzureDevOps&category=Azure%20Pipelines&visibilityQuery=all&sortBy=Relevance) I find some Assembly Info task extensions from the Marketplace. You can install one suitable extension from them to your organization and then call the related task in your build pipeline.

Below is a similar topic as reference:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/8452320/14697693

Comment: Hello,

thanks for the answer.
With the Assembly Info Task I can only edit .cs and .vb files. I have tried almost all the others again now and they all don't want the .rc file. The project is a C++ .vcpoj from VisualStudio2008 without .Net.
In the other thread, the way was requested via an MSBUILD argument. But it is not clear to me where to start this in the project? Where and in which file do I insert the target section?